# Infinite loop when debugging in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, infinite-loop

I have a strange issue with VS2010 (building a large C++ project). When starting to debug, the execution goes in something like an infinite loop. I put the a breakpoint at the first line of main(), but the breakpoint is never reached. I also tried F11 to step into main(), but no effect. The task manager shows an instance of my application, and the console says nothing but "xxx.dll Symbols loaded.". I tried to pause the execution, but I get thrown into some assembly loop, here is the assembly if someone can read it:

```
0000000077226129  lea         rdx,[rsp+88h]  
0000000077226131  xor         ecx,ecx  
0000000077226133  call        0000000077231650  
0000000077226138  mov         dword ptr [rsp+30h],eax  
000000007722613C  test        eax,eax  
000000007722613E  js          000000007725E73F  
0000000077226144  cmp         dword ptr [7731201Ch],r14d  
000000007722614B  je          0000000077226129
```

Can someone tell me or at least point me to how to approach this problem?

**Edit:** I found out that when removing one of the shared libraries (FlyCapture2 developed by Point Grey Research), the application starts normally. It seems that the library has some kind of loading routite, which is called before the execution of main(). Even though I solved my current problem, I still would like to know: how to detect such kind of problems?

Comment: Don't show assembly, show the call stack.

Comment: There is no call stack, the application does not even finish loading the DLL's...

Comment: So does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the problem.
In one of my DLLs I had a singleton class. In the header file i had an getter *LogManager::instance()* and an destroyer *void LogManager::destroyInstance()*. The instance was defined in the .cpp file but not statically but just as global variable

```
LogManager* sInstance = new LogManager;
```

and the *instance()* function just returned that variable and the *destroyInstance()* function deleted it. So I removed the global variable and created that instance within the *instance()* function

```
void LogManager::instance()
{
    static LogManager*  sInstance = 0;
        if(!sInstance)
            sInstance = new LogManager;
    return sInstance;
}
```

and the problem was gone. So I think maybe the global variable in that DLL caused an infinite loop during loading of that DLL?
Maybe thats an hint for people with similar problems.

Comment: Actually, the initialization routine of the DLL can have any number of errors. The actual question was, how can you tell the debugger "please stop at the first line of code in any of my DLLs or in the executable". After three years of experience, I figured it out :) You can't, unless you have the source code or at least debugging symbols for the DLL(s).

Comment: You can still dissassemble and try to figure out the error :) but i guess you are right, this error is hard to fix and rarely.

Answer (score 0):

How to connect to DLL(s) correctly is a big problem.It is before applications so we are hard to find it and solve it.But when I hava a question about DLL(s),I would also look for answers on the Internet.And every error has its own serial number.That's the key.It also says "LNK****  ........" in the "Error List".So I can find it ,and even solve it by myself according to the information from others.

PS:Your code is called "Machine Instruction".It's part of Principles of Computer.